# Пунктуация в обороте "сказанул(?) так сказанул"

Tags: пунктуация, грамматика, морфология

Какой частью речи является здесь слово "так"? Как называется оборот и как расставить в нём знаки препинания?

Верно ли: "**сказанул — так сказанул**"?

Answer (score 2):

**СКАЗАНУ́ТЬ,** совер., ***что*** и ***без дополнения*** (*просторечное, фамильярное, шутливое*).
Сказать, произнести.
*Ну и сказанул ты штуку! Он тебе и не такое сказанет.*
[Cинонимы: брякнуть, бу́хнуть, выдать, загнуть, отпустить, сморозить, хватить, ляпнуть.]

**Сказанул так сказанул** — *осложненное глагольное сказуемое* (простое глагольное сказуемое, выраженное сочетанием двух глаголов или сочетанием глагола с различными частицами).
В *нашем* случае повторяется сказуемое с усилительной частицей **так** —  для обозначения высокой степени осуществленного действия(запятая или тире не ставятся).
[**Осложненное глагольное сказуемое**](http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/lingvistic/996/%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5)

*От*[вот] ***сказанул так сказанул***, в луже пузыри...
Вот это **сказанул так сказанул**: в стиле индийского кино.
...мрачно сказал я и до боли прикусил язык: вот **ляпнул так ляпнул**!
Учили меня отец мои и мать: любить так любить, гулять так гулять, лечить так лечить, стрелять так стрелять...